# ListBox and populating with .RowSource - how to set the sheet name as "external variable" - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, database, listbox, worksheet

i'm trying to populate some sheet with values from an userform, i got a problem trying to specify sheet name on listbox since i want to split the database based on week number.

This is the portion of my code that populate the listbox (sheet name will comes from TextBox5). Right now it works fine but i'm using only worksheet "Data" as you can see:

```
Sub Refresh_Data()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Me.TextBox5.Text)
Dim last_Row As Long
last_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 12
        .ColumnWidths = "30;60;90;50;90;70;30;80;50;150;50;150"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        
        If last_Row = 1 Then
        .RowSource = "Data!A2:L2"
        Else
        .RowSource = "Data!A2:L" & last_Row
        End If
         
End With
End Sub
```

How do i replace Data in the if cycle to be Data1/Data2/etc... Thank you in advance. I'm a neewbie with VBA and self learning (aka copy/pasting everything...)

Comment: Do  you mean: `.RowSource = "'" & sh.name & "'!A2:L2"` for example?

Comment: It was excatly what i was looking for... Thank you very much